# Freenas and ACL permissions

Tags: permissions, freebsd, acl, smb, freenas

I have been trying to set up the ACL on FreeNas 11.3 all day and it just does not work the way I think it should I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

All I want to do is when a user creates a file in a folder, that new file or directory it will have permissions `rwxrwx---`. I have tried, what I think is, every combination of owner@, group@, Group, User, and everyone@ with every permission and flag option. No matter what I set the flags for inheritance it always comes out exactly the same or denies me from creating a new file/folder.

When a new file is made, the permissions are `-rw-r--r--` and when a new folder is made the permissions are `drwxrwx---`. When I try to change the ACLs and I set it to be recursive, then it will change the permissions of the files existing files to what I want them to be, but when I create a new file, the new file is right back to that same `-rw-r--r--`. I don't understand what I need to do.

I have used getfacl, So here is what is really weird. I have around 7 datasets. One is named Admin, and another is named Operations. They have the exact same output when I check them with the getfacl command, but in Operations, when I create a new file it automatically comes up with the permissions I am looking for. In Admin when I create a new file it makes it something different. Is there any reason that the ACLs would be the same but when files are created they have different permissions?

**Edit**

Below is the output of the `mount` command:

```
freenas-boot/ROOT/11.3-U3.2 on / (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, multilabel)
tmpfs on /etc (tmpfs, local)
tmpfs on /mnt (tmpfs, local)
tmpfs on /var (tmpfs, local)
fdescfs on /dev/fd (fdescfs)
Business_Data on /mnt/Business_Data (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Share on /mnt/Business_Data/Share (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Projects on /mnt/Business_Data/Projects (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Users on /mnt/Business_Data/Users (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Archives on /mnt/Business_Data/Archives (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/iocage on /mnt/Business_Data/iocage (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Operations on /mnt/Business_Data/Operations (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Marketing on /mnt/Business_Data/Marketing (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Financial on /mnt/Business_Data/Financial (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Human Resources on /mnt/Business_Data/Human Resources (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/Administrative on /mnt/Business_Data/Administrative (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/iocage/download on /mnt/Business_Data/iocage/download (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/iocage/jails on /mnt/Business_Data/iocage/jails (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/iocage/templates on /mnt/Business_Data/iocage/templates (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/iocage/log on /mnt/Business_Data/iocage/log (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/iocage/releases on /mnt/Business_Data/iocage/releases (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/iocage/images on /mnt/Business_Data/iocage/images (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/.system on /var/db/system (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/.system/cores on /var/db/system/cores (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/.system/samba4 on /var/db/system/samba4 (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/.system/syslog-b34611ec74194ef89937f2d1ccaf453a on /var/db/system/syslog-b34611ec74194ef89937f2d1ccaf453a (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/.system/rrd-b34611ec74194ef89937f2d1ccaf453a on /var/db/system/rrd-b34611ec74194ef89937f2d1ccaf453a (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/.system/configs-b34611ec74194ef89937f2d1ccaf453a on /var/db/system/configs-b34611ec74194ef89937f2d1ccaf453a (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
Business_Data/.system/webui on /var/db/system/webui (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
```

Output of `getfacl` on Projects Dataset, and the Operations Dataset

```
# file: Projects
# owner: kevin
# group: ALL_emp
    group:ALL_emp:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
            owner@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
            group@:rwxpDdaARWc--s:fd-----:allow
         everyone@:--------------:fd-----:allow

# file: Operations
# owner: kevin
# group: ALL_emp
    group:ALL_emp:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
            owner@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
            group@:rwxpDdaARWc--s:fd-----:allow
         everyone@:--------------:fd-----:allow
```

When I create a file from my windows computer in Projects and run `ls -al`:

```
-rw-rwxr--+   1 kevin     ALL_emp      0 Jun 26 15:58 New Text Document.txt
```

When I create a file from my windows computer in Operations and run `ls -al`:

```
-rwxrwx---+  1 kevin  ALL_emp   0 Jun 26 16:01 New Text Document.txt
```

Please let me know if there is any other detail I can provide.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of the `umask` command?

Comment: it is `022`, which should give `-----w--w-`. I have tried setting it to `770` but I get the same thing when a file is created.

Comment: If your assumption what the umask value means is correct then BSD then it is the opposite of what it is in Linux. I doubt that. Under Linux the umask value masks the permissions i.e. the permissions given in the umask are **not** granted. And execute permissions for a file have to be requested by the creating application.

Comment: You have not shown what happens. "something goes wrong" is not enough. However my guess is mount points (I will assume that one of your attempts was correct). Did you check the ACLs with `getfacl`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging `umask` is the same in BSD, Gnu/Linux, system-V: `755` gives `----w--w-`. It is a mask, each 1 blocks a bit, thus forcing it to 0. If a bit is not blocked it is what ever the app tries to make it be.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have used `getfacl`, So here is what is really weird. I have around 7 datasets. One is named Admin, and another is named Operations. They have the exact same output when I check them with the `getfacl` command, but in Operations, when I create a new file it automatically comes up with the permissions I am looking for. In Admin when I create a new file it makes it something different. Is there any reason that the ACL's would be the same but when files are created they have different permissions?

Comment: @HaukeLaging thank you for explaining umask to me, you are right. I was thinking about that backwords.

Comment: I moved your comment into your question (by clicking edit). However it is very specify, but has the detail in the wrong place. Show us what you did. And show output of `findmnt`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor FreeNas I don't believe has `findmnt`, but I looked it up and they said `mount` should be the equivalent. I have also added the outputs of `getfacl`of the datasets and `ls -al` for newly created files.